# get array position in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to pass the the incremented value of `mPath[]` to my new intent using bundle. But I am not sure how to increment it.

```
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
{        
    String path_name = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getString(3);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, path_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mPath[i] = "http://www.mywebsite.com/tattoo/" + path_name;        
}

list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, mImages);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("selection", mPath[INCREMENT]);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowFullSize.class);
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make use of the position of item from listview and increment the value of array as you want.

```
 `list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, mImages);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//instead of INCREMENT here use arg2 which gives you the position of the list item clciked.
    bundle.putString("selection", mPath[arg2]);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowFullSize.class);
    myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
}
});
```

`

Answer (score 1):

if your mstrings/mImages size was same as the mPath then you can pass the 3rd parameter value that is index/position. for e.g.

```
bundle.putString("selection", mPath[arg2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){


    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowFullSize.class);
    INCREMENT=INCREMENT+1;
    myIntent.putExtras("selection", mPath[INCREMENT]);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 


                        }
                    });
```

To retrieve in ShowFullSize Activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String selection=bundle.getString("selection");
```